# Regex to find words from list, when specific words not appear 3 words before

Tags: r, regex

I want to find all matches of specific words from list, but when specific another words not appears in the range of 3 words before.

For example:

Find all the times that the words "good|best|better" appears in the text, but the words "no|not|none" not appears 3 words before.

I tried something like that:

```
(?<!\sno|\snot(\s|\s\w\s|\s\w\s\w\s))(\bgood\b|\bbest\b|\bbetter\b)
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean with `it's not working.`?

Comment: I work with R, with the function gregexpr

Comment: Example: in the sentence: "The car was not very good but the trip was the best possible", I dont want to find the word "good", because the word "not" appears before, but I want to find the word "best"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use this `PCRE` regex in `R` with `perl=TRUE` option:

```
\b(?:not?|none)(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s+(good|best|better)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(?:good|best|better)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ewWYx/1)

In your `R` code use:

```
gregexpr("\\b(?:not?|none)(?:\\s+\\S+){0,2}\\s+(good|best|better)\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b(?:good|best|better)\\b", mystr, perl=TRUE)
```

In `PCRE`, verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` are used to fail and skip a match that we don't want to match.

Comment: make sure to use `perl=TRUE` option

Answer (score 0):

If we would be only looking to fail `no` and other derivatives of that, we would be starting with a simple expression such as:

```
^(?!.*no).*times.*$
```

Then, we would add word boundary if necessary, and we would expand that to:

```
^(?!.*\bno\b|.*\bnot\b|.*\bnone\b).*times.*$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/H8Oemh/1/)

and finally we would add our desired words using:

```
^(?!.*\bno\b|.*\bnot\b|.*\bnone\b)(?=.*\bgood\b|.*\bbest\b|.*\bbetter\b).*times.*$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/AXGjeC/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]